# specifying the path for input data and output data

Tags: java

I am new in java and I have to use the code below but the code it does work because I have to specifying  the path for  input data and output data. The code is got it from the internet. please help me

```
class Svm_scale 
{


    private BufferedReader rewind(BufferedReader fp, String filename) throws IOException
    {
        fp.close();
        return new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
    }

    private void output_target(double value)
    {
        LnCount++;
        if(y_scaling)
        {
            if(value == y_min)
                value = y_lower;
            else if(value == y_max)
                value = y_upper;
            else
                value = y_lower + (y_upper-y_lower) *
                (value-y_min) / (y_max-y_min);
        }
formatterscaled.format(value+" ");
     System.out.println(" Line Number "+LnCount + " ");
    }

    private void output(int index, double value)
    {
        count++;
        double Threshold1=0,Threshold2=0;


        Threshold1= Avg[index]+(STDV[index]/2);
        Threshold2= Avg[index]-(STDV[index]/2);


        if(value > Threshold1 )
          value = 2;
        else if(value < Threshold2 )
        value = -2;
        else
        value = 0;


           formatterscaled.format( formatter.format(value) + ",");



       //    System.out.println(" Counter "+count);
     //   }
    }
```

Comment: Are you asking about command line arguments?

Comment: Please post a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and explain what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks@Karthikeyan Vaithilingam. the code is designed to discretize  a dataset  to three categories (-2,0,2) and i need to know where should I put the path of the input data and the path of the output data (the discretized data).

Comment: Thanks@jsheeran. As I mentioned the problem is to how discretize a data into three ccategories (-2,0,2)? which is done by this code and i need to know where should I put the path of the input data and the path of the output data (the discretized data)

Comment: just guessing as your code is not complete and as such wouldn't even compile. Look at the `exit_with_help` method. Do the options there make sense to you? may they work? Besides those file-options I believe that the rest of the program is just written to the console.

Comment: No, this is the whole code just omitted the area of Identifiers.

Comment: As you already put lots of code in there, you may also want to put the rest. With this code only guessing is possible. Did you already try what I suggested?

Comment: yes@Roland I have uploaded the whole code and omitted the method exit_with_help because I found it does not made any change in the program.but still getting the same error

Comment: which error do you get? Try the adapted answer. By replacing the `String` values the program should work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
String save_filename =Save1; // = null?
String restore_filename =null;
String scale_data_filename =Disc; // set this to the path where the output should be stored, e.g. = "C:\\temp\\scaled";
String data_filename =Libsvm; // set this to the path where the input can be get, e.g. = "C:\\temp\\inputdata"
```

These are the `String`s you need to adapt in order that the program can read and write. `Save1`, `Disc`, `Libsvm` are not in your code, so it can only be guessed where they come from.

`data_filename` and `scale_data_filename` are required. `save_filename` seems to be optional and may be set to `null`.

Comment: yes, the actual class is ADisSvm_scale but how Libsvm might lead to the solution?

Comment: thanks a lot @roland . it was a great. the code now is working.

Comment: wondering why the answer is still negative? As suggestion: the next time don't put half of the code in here, rather try to find out where the missing pieces could be or at least mention what you tried or which error messages you encounter.